# JS remove last child?

Tags: javascript

When I add a few of `<select>` ex. `SELECT_country, SELECT_country1,  SELECT_country2`
I would like to remove them in the order of appearance from the newest one to oldest one. But it is removing from oldest one to newest one. I thought `SELECT_country` is *parent*, and I will be deleting its *child*, but the *parent* goes away first.

How I can change it?

```
var j = 0;

function add_country() {
    j++;
    var select = document.getElementById("SELECT_country");
    var clone = select.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute("id", "SELECT_country" + j);
    clone.setAttribute("name", "country" + j);
    document.getElementById("DIV_country").appendChild(clone);
}

function remove_country() {
    var select = document.getElementById('SELECT_country');
    select.parentNode.removeChild(select);
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Since you are appending new elements you need to get the last element by using [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) if you want to remove them from newest to oldest.

```
function remove_country() {
  var select = document.getElementById('DIV_country');
  select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rrkroxcb/1/**

Comment: Isn't `select.lastChild.parentNode` always equal to `select`?

Comment: Use [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild) if you want to avoid text nodes.